# Account merging

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, multiple-accounts

I have an issue with account merging form in the help center. The 'Your other profile link' does not accept any link to the second my account.

[image: Picture 1: completed help form]
**Picture 1: Completed help form**

[image]
**Picture 2: Outcome of pressing the 'Submit' button for the setting as in Picture 1**

The issue is reproduced on different browsers:

- Opera One (version: 101.0.4843.33)
- Google Chrome (Version 116.0.5845.111 (Official Build) (64-bit) )

I have seen quite a few similar issues over different communities META, none of which was resolved:

- [Can't open a ticket for merging accounts; Error occurs even though all fields are included](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389841)
- [I need help to merge two profiles I have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426064)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As referenced [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392952/344828), I've fixed this issue. Please let me know if you're continuing to experience any problems, and thanks for reporting the issue!

Comment: Thank you! It seems that, meanwhile, my accounts have been merged manually!